# perl + Match last number in file and reduce it by one

Tags: bash, solaris, perl

I want to add the following perl command in my bash script please advice

how to change (reduce by one ) the last number that start with "+" character in file with perl ?

```
Example of original file   ( before run the perl command )

more file




432423
53454
+535
343
45
+1000
```

example of requested output file ( after run the perl command )

```
more file




432423
53454
+535
343
45
+999
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I hear "do something on the LAST occurrance of ...", I reach for [`tac`](http://man.cx/tac) to reverse the lines, and do something on the FIRST occurrance.

```
tac file | nawk '/^\+/&&!done {$1 = "+" substr($1,2)-1; done=1} 1' | tac
```

On Solaris, you may not have tac installed. You can implement it like [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/tac.html):

```
tac() { sed -n -e '1!G' -e '$p' -e h "$@"; }
```

Comment: I get this - sed -n -e '1!G' -e '$p' -e h "$@" file | awk '/^\+/&&!done {$1 = "+" substr($1,2)-1; done=1} 1' | sed -n -e '1!G' -e '$p' -e h "$@" awk: syntax error near line 1 awk: bailing out near line 1 ( mybe awk syntax not fit solaris ) ?

Comment: @yael, I should have specified, on Solaris use `nawk` instead of `awk`. `/usr/bin/awk` is known as "the old, broken awk".

Comment: now work but not reduce the number --> echo 10 >/var/tmp/file ; sed -n -e '1!G' -e '$p' -e h "$@" file | nawk '/^\+/&&!done {$1 = "+" substr($1,2)-1; done=1} 1' | sed -n -e '1!G' -e '$p' -e h "$@"   --> the outout  10

Comment: You specified the number must begin with a "+". Also, you have to define the function, don't just take the function body out of context: `echo +10 > tmpfile; tac tmpfile | nawk '/^\+/&&!done {$1 = "+" substr($1,2)-1; done=1} 1' | tac` outputs `+9`

Answer (score 1):

You can the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

open(INFILE, "< file") or die( "Can't open input file" );
open(OUTFILE, "> file.out") or die( "Can't open output file" );
my @lines = reverse <INFILE>;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    if ($line =~ /^\+(\d+)/) {
        $line = "+".($1-1)."\n";
        last;
    }
}
my @lines2 = reverse @lines;
foreach my $line (@lines2) {
    print OUTFILE $line;
}
close(OUTFILE);
```

Comment: yes but the original question is to add this command in my bash , I don't want different perl script

Comment: What can't you call the perl script from bash? Yeah, you can make Khaled's script into a one-liner inside a bash script, but that would horrible.